# Referencing a module in another folder without creating again the resource - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

It's possible to reference a resource from another folder without creating again the resource?

Let me first try to describe the structure:

```
..prod/
..  .. prod.tf
..staging/
.. .. staging.tf
..modules/
.. .. resourceX/
.. .. .. main.tf
.. .. .. output.tf
.. .. resourceY/
.. .. .. main.tf
.. .. .. vars.tf
```

On resourceX/main.tf:

```
resource "resource" "resourceX" {
  ...
}
```

On resourceX/output.tf

```
output "resourceX_name" {
    value = resource.resourceX.name
}
```

On prod.tf:

```
module "resourceX" {
  source = ....modules/resourceX
  ...
}
```

On staging.tf

```
module "resourceY" {
  source = ...modules/resourceY
  resourceX_name = module.resourceX.resourceX_name
  ...
}
```

On resourceY/vars.tf:

```
variable "resourceX_name" {
    type = string
}
```

On resourceY/main.tf:

```
resource "resource" "resourceY" {
  attach = var.resourceX_name
}
```

---

Now, when I try to:

```
terraform apply --target=module.staging.module.resourceY
```

Works great but wants to create again the resource previously create with resourceX. What it's the best approach to fix that?

I tried the solution provide in [Referencing Terraform resource created in a different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64094992/referencing-terraform-resource-created-in-a-different-folder) but I got the same result.

Comment: Sorry for the delay Marcin, I just put the name of the resource that I need to make the "reference" instead of trying to use the reference mechanisms. It isn't the most elegant way, but it should not change the name of the resource so...
Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't create two resources with same ID**, which is going to happen because of:

```
resource "resource" "resourceY" {
  attach = var.resourceX_name
}
```

if you only want to use `var.resourceX_name` as reference in other resources then you do it directly. You don't need to re-create the resource again as you are trying to do now.